# Python-Selenium-YearMonth-Increment-Submit

Tags: python, selenium, increment, python-3.9

I have a question about Python 3.9.12 Selenium.

So far I coded via python selenium to perform actions stated below,

1. auto login(as admin) a business email Website that I'm currently working as an IT Admin
2. When I'm logged in, make selenium to order the webdriver, to get a email backup page, which only admins can access.
3. The backup page GUI requires me to input the `backupee's username`, `backup year,month(In YYYYMM Format)`, and to press `submit button` (For example If the Backupee has been working for 3years since 202001, I have to do this process multiple times without selenium.

#3 Kind of looks like this in a table form

| Username | YearMonth(YYYYMM) | submit`button` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 201001 | `Submit` |

That's pretty much it and I was able to code it so far to make it to press the submit button after putting in all the infos that the backupwebpage requires,

**But the problem that I'm encountering is,**
I can't find out how to

1. make the code to do the same job but only increase 1month every time and Press `submit`

   - ex)`1st input→Username(same)|202001|submit` (1st selenium initialization)
   - ex)`2nd input→Username(same)|202002|submit` (automation)
   - .(automation)
   - .(automation)
   - ex)`12th input→Username(same)|202012|submit` (automation)
   - ex)`13th input→Username(same)|202101|submit` (automation)
2. make selenium to stop when it reaches intended year month

   - ex) `Intended YearMonth:202212`
     -`26th input→202211`
     -`27th input→202212` (stops because selenium reached its intended YearMonth)

Here's my full code, please forgive me that I can't actually include the website's link due to security reasons.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

import A_Info

#Variable Designation
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

#For Definition
def firstscr():
    driver.get('link')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element_by_id("cid").send_keys(A_Info.id)
    driver.find_element_by_id('cpw').send_keys(A_Info.pw)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('mb-auth-login-button').click() #Next Screen Transition
def secondscr():
    driver.get('link')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
def naming():
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('auto_complete-chosen').click()
    el1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('auto_complete-input')
    el1.send_keys('John Doe') #input Backupee of your choice
    el1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
def date():
    date = datetime.strptime("2010,1,1","%Y,%m,%d")
    Mydate = date.strftime("%Y%m")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#md_date').send_keys(Mydate)
def submit():
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#add_backup').click()

#For Activation 
firstscr()
secondscr()
naming()
date()
submit()
```

**If there are any recommendations that I can try, please let me know.
Thank you in advance.**

Comment: standard rule: to repeat something you need `for`-loop or `while`-loop.

Comment: You would be using incrementing the start date +relativedelta(months=1) until you hit the current date.

Comment: you should create function `date()` which gets date as `datatime` and then you could run it in loop which use `date = date + datetime.timedelta(months=1)` to get next months

Answer (score 0):

Standard rule: to repeat something you need loop (`for`-loop or `while`-loop).  (I skip `recursion`)

First: your function `date()` should get date directly as `datetime`

```
def date(new_date):
    Mydate = new_date.strftime("%Y%m")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#md_date').send_keys(Mydate)

some_date = datetime.strptime("2010,1,1","%Y,%m,%d")
new_date(some_date)
```

or as string `"202212"`

```
def date(Mydate):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#md_date').send_keys(Mydate)

some_date = datetime.strptime("2010,1,1","%Y,%m,%d")
Mydate = new_date.strftime("%Y%m")
new_date(Mydate)
```

(and frankly at this moment it could be simpler to put this directly in loop without function `date()` - but I skip it)

I had to use different names for variables because you can't have variable `date` and function `date` at the same time.

And now you can run in loop like

```
some_date = datetime.strptime("2010,1,1","%Y,%m,%d")

end = '202212'

firstscr()
secondscr()
naming()

while some_date.strftime("%Y%m") <= end:

    new_date(some_date)
    submit()

    some_date += datetime.timedelta(months=1)
```

---

I can't run it so I don't know if it need some changes. Maybe it needs to run `naming()` also in loop, or maybe it needs to load backup page again, etc.

Comment: That loop was the exact thing I'm looking for!! Thank you so much

I'll try out and let you know how things worked out!

Comment: hello, it's been quite some time since I last answered you, 

I just wanted to tell you that it worked like a charm

Thanks a bunch, you saved me a lot of time

have a lovely week ^_^